# How to add at least one CSS class to a twig region?

Tags: theming, 10

I am trying to add CSS classes to a new region `{{ page.example }}` in page.html.twig

In the start of page.html.twig, I have added a set of CSS classes:

```
{%
set classes = [
  'region--content', 
  'grid-full', 
  'layout--pass--content-medium',
]
%}
```

When I try to apply them to an element as follows, this element just disappears from my node.

```
{{ page.example.addClass(classes) }}
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Maybe is due to https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3178202? Namely, is the "example" variable a string or a renderable array?

Comment: I don't know the Twig terminology to say if it is a Twig string or a Twig renderable array but if I would have had to guess I'd guess that it is not a string of any kind but indeed a renderable array. It's just like `{{ page.content_above }}` and `{{page.content}}` and `{{ page.content_below }}`, nothing special beyond that.

Comment: I meant you shuld inspect via debug or dump it to check that. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/discovering-and-inspecting-variables-in-twig-templates or https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/debugging-twig-templates You could also use twig_tweaks module and `dd()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a simple way to add at least one class with Twig so I have added classes with HTML this way:

```html
<div class="region--content grid-full layout--pass--content-medium">
  {{ page.example }}
</div>
```

I have flushed all caches of Drupal with Drush and flushed all caches of the web browser to test the webpage appearance and indeed found this change to work.